# MySQL Multi Table Search

Tags: mysql, multi-table

```
table1
 ID
 SUBJECT
 CONTENT

table2
 ID
 SUBJECT
 CONTENT

table3
 ID
 SUBJECT
 CONTENT

... 5 more
```

I want to search `SUBJECT` on all the tables

How can I do this?

Comment: Are the tables all the same structure?  If so, why aren't they normalized into one table?  If not, how do you plan on combining the results?  Are you doing a FULL-TEXT search or just a regular search?

Comment: All the same structure as Tables But Contents of the different.

Answer (score 2):

```
CREATE VIEW multitable AS
SELECT * FROM table1
UNION SELECT * from table2
UNION SELECT * from table3;

SELECT subject FROM multitable ...
```

Comment: its working but my db total size 1.5 GB and this method wait to much.
do you have any idea ?

Comment: How does the performance compare to the other solutions suggested here? What does `EXPLAIN SELECT subject FROM multitable...` say? What does running `EXPLAIN` on the other solutions say? Note that you can also profile the queries with `SET profiling = 1`, `SELECT ...`, `SHOW PROFILES`.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from table1 where subject like '%match%' union
select * from table2 where subject like '%match%' union
select * from table3 where subject like '%match%' union
select * from table4 where subject like '%match%' union
select * from table5 where subject like '%match%' union
select * from table6 where subject like '%match%' union
select * from table7 where subject like '%match%' union
select * from table8 where subject like '%match%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Because all the tables have the same syntax, you can use the `UNION` operator.

```
SELECT * FROM Table1
UNION Table2
UNION Table3
UNION Table4
UNION Table5
UNION Table6
UNION Table7
UNION Table8
WHERE SUBJECT="Subject"
```

For the sake of simplicity, 8 tables isn't too much to write out. If you had more, I'd recommend a [dynamic query](http://datacharmer.blogspot.com/2005/10/power-of-dynamic-queries.html).